# Stop or pause button - Accelerometer

Tags: android, xml

I'm new with this and I need some help..Tried to find something similar to my problem, but i couldn't fix it.
I found a code for accelerometar with 3 axis(X,Y,Z) and I'm trying to add a button which will stop this proccess and "record" these three values (just to stop them). Can anyone help me?

here is the code:

```
package course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues;


public class SensorRawAccelerometerActivity extends Activity implements
        SensorEventListener {


    private static final int UPDATE_THRESHOLD = 500;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;

    private TextView mXValueView, mYValueView, mZValueView;
    private long mLastUpdate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mXValueView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_value_view);
        mYValueView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_value_view);
        mZValueView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_value_view);

        // Get reference to SensorManager
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Get reference to Accelerometer
        if (null == (mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)))
            finish();

    }

    // Register listener
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

        mLastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    // Unregister listener
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    // Process new reading
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (actualTime - mLastUpdate > UPDATE_THRESHOLD) {

                mLastUpdate = actualTime;

                float x = event.values[0], y = event.values[1], z = event.values[2];

                mXValueView.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                mYValueView.setText(String.valueOf(y));
                mZValueView.setText(String.valueOf(z));

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // N/A
    }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >





    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/raw_x_string"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/y_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/x_value"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/raw_y_string"
        android:textSize="24sp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/z_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/y_value"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/raw_z_string"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x_value_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/x_value"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/y_value_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/x_value_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/y_value"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/z_value_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/y_value_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/z_value"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

thank you a lot! 
Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a button to your XML file with the property:

```
android:onClick="myMethodName"
```

Create a new private boolean variable in your activity to keep track of if you are updating or not (in this case I called it updating). Modify your activity to include:

```
public void myMethodName(View v)
{
    //if updating, stop updating. if not updating, start updating
    updating = !updating;
}
```

This method is called whenever your button is pressed. This method's name must match whatever you put in the onClick field in your XML. Finally, modify your onSensorChanged method to look like this:

```
onSensorChanged(Event e)
{
    if(updating)
    {
    //do everything else you already do here
    }
}
```

Now it will update until the button is pressed, at which point it will stop updating but continue showing the last value until the button is pressed again.